# CSS and JQuery: how to remove "right:0" style

Tags: jquery, css, position

I am using a tool for a web project. The tool comes with CSS. However, its CSS affects the display of a particular interface element (this element has "position: absolute"). After tracking and experiments, I notice that if I remove (via Firebug in Firefox, for example) the "right:0" style from the tool's CSS rule, everything looks perfect.

I cannot modify the tool's CSS because it generally works well with the rest of the web application and it only has an issue with that particular interface element.

I read many posts online and at SO and tried different ways and came up with no success. I tried the following:

1. Create a CSS rule with high priority.

   #element {
       right: none; 
   }

This does not work. I cannot use "right: XXpx" approach because the XX has to change with the screen resize.

1. Use JQuery:

   $('#element').css('right', '')

This does not work either.

Does anybody know how to remove "right:0" style from a "position:absolute" element?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to set it to `auto` :
`right: auto;`

In your case it will be:
`#element { right: auto; }`

No need in jQuery!

Working: http://jsfiddle.net/fEThD/1/

Comment: Yes. `auto` is the default, the initial value.

Comment: @Cherniv, thanks sooooo much for your super fast and working solution!!! Two questions: Just for discussion, is it possible to remove "right:0"?

Comment: @curious1 I mean absolutely no offense, but... "Two questions"??

Comment: @curious1 AFAIK , browser "remembers" all css rules , even those that are not "relevant " at this current time  , so .. you cannot actually remove "right:0" , but as we see it is possible to redefine it

Comment: The second question is here: "right:auto" serves what purpose? Removing the style? Or set it to a different value? What value?

Comment: @curious1 `auto` is the default value. Next time search the mdn for the css style you're trying to override to see what it's default value is. You can't actually remove the style, so the next best thing is to override it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right